# Runtime error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I am new to odoo and I received this error when I added a function in inherited sale_order_line class.Below is the code. Could you please let me know where I did the blunder?

```
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product', domain=[('sale_ok', '=', True)],
                             change_default=True, ondelete='restrict', required=True)

    salesman_id = fields.Char(string='Salesman')

    @api.onchange(product_id)
    @api.depends(salesman_id)
    def user_id_tracking(self):
        self.env.cr.execute("""SELECT user_id FROM stock_location as sl WHERE sl.id in
        (SELECT sq.location_id FROM stock_change_product_qty as sq,product_template as pt
        WHERE sq.product_id = %d)""", self.product_id)
        res = self.env.cr.fetchone()
        self.salesman_id = res[0]

    lot_id = fields.Many2one('stock.production.lot', string='Lot/Serial Number', copy=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling odoo to trigger this function when you change the  `salesman_id` and inside that function you change the same field so odoo will keep calling your method.

```
remove depends decorator because you are using it the wrong way use it only for compute field.
```

just keep `onchange` and never `set` the **same field** that you **depend on** to compute the field value.